# Countif(s) criteria is a range plus a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, criteria, countif

I would like to countif(s) a range is greater than another range plus 3.

Here is what I currently have that isn't working (only the 3rd criteria isn't working):

```
=COUNTIFS($F:$F, ">" &G:G,F:F, ">1",F:F, "<" &G:G+3)
```

Isolating the issue to a single row works, a la:

```
=COUNTIF(F12, "<" &G12+3)
```

I am trying to get the countifs to check if an F cell in a given row is less than a G cell +3 for the same row.

Comment: The cells in each column are either blank, contain a date, or contain text. The formula you gave me returns a #VALUE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a formula that supports arrays for that, like the following, entered with ctrl+shift+enter, instead of the regular Enter

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(--$F1:$F100),0,IF(ISERROR(--$F1:$F100),0,IF($F1:$F100>G1:G100,IF(F1:F100>1,IF(F1:F100<G1:G100+3,1,0),0),0))))
```

Comment: I don't think that AND() plays well with array formulas. Usually better with successive IF(IF(... functions.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, I've fixed that, though with a `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

Comment: The cells in each column are either blank, contain a date, or contain text.  The formula you gave me returns a #VALUE!